# Pass sysname in datatable TVP

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure using the type below as a param

```
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[columnOrderTableType] AS TABLE
     ([id]                     [int]        IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
     ,[columnName]             [sysname]                  NOT NULL
```

I need to pass a datatable from my api as TVP to this sproc

When I use string as value for the columnName I get an error saying that type doesnt match the types reqd for columnOrderTableType

How do I pass a sysname in datatable?

Comment: Why don't you change your TVP to use `nvarchar`? Just because the system metadata uses `sysname` doesn't mean it's a good idea for you to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the data to nvarchar(128) and using nvarchar instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240(v=sql.105).aspx